# Edit the contents of "getChildHtml('content')" in 1column.phtml

Tags: magento-1.7, template

I'm looking for editing the contents of my template in the page **1column.phtml**.

This page looks like this :

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_notices') ?>
    <div class="page">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header') ?>
        <div class="main-container col1-layout leave">
            <div class="main">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>
                <div class="col-main">
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('before_body_end') ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I would to change is generated by `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>`, but I have no idea where the find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>`

This code call the contents which resides in your cms pages.
So go to your cms page whichever it is and edit something over there and see the results.